# How to save a Datatable as a CSV file on client pc ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, csv, client-side

How would one go about saving a dataset as a CSV file to a client pc?

I Can save a file from the server to a client pc, and I can convert a Datatable to a CSV file, but I cant seem to figure out how to put the two together.

Save file from server to client (as attachment)

```
String FileName = "my file name";
String FilePath = @"C:\testfile.txt";
System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.ClearContent();
response.Clear();
response.ContentType = "text/plain";
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName + ";");

response.TransmitFile(FilePath + FileName); //Can only put the file path in here, cant put the datatable or convertion in there.. 
response.Flush();
response.End();
```

Convert datatable to CSV file (since I have a datatable that should be saved as a CSV file to the client pc)

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 

string[] columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                  Select(column => column.ColumnName).
                                  ToArray();
sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    string[] fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString()).
                                    ToArray();
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
}

File.WriteAllText("test.csv", sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use the `response.Write(sb.ToString());` and not the `response.TransmitFile` to render to the output yours CSV generated data. For example:

```
response.ClearContent();
response.Clear();
response.ContentType = "text/plain";
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=DownloadedData.txt;");

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 

string[] columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                  Select(column => column.ColumnName).
                                  ToArray();
sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    string[] fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString()).
                                    ToArray();
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
}

// the most easy way as you have type it
response.Write(sb.ToString());


response.Flush();
response.End();
```

and is better to use a handler, and not do that from the page.

Comment: That worked great thanks. Didn't know you can do that with response.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing to File object, write to Response object. When you will say "Response.End();", it will prompt to save the file

Answer (score 0):

U can try this code, this creates an xls file as an attachment

```
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileEName.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    this.EnableViewState = false;
    Response.Write("PASS YOUR STRING HERE");
    Response.End();
```